# Updating Remote Configuration data when a user property changes

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I use Firebase Remote configuration to control my app features per user segment and so I apply conditions on remote configuration parameter based on some user properties.

The issue is that some of these user properties could be changed when the app user make some actions that change his/her segment (like user was free user and becomes a paid users) and in this case, Remote configuration doesn't fetch the new values so the user sees wrong data in the current app session (sees data related to his previous segment not the new one) and will not see the right data until he/she closes the app and opens it again.

-Are there any solution to force Remote Configuration to update the cached value?
-Is it right to use Remote Configuration in these case or we have to move to another solution like RTDB?

Comment: Are you fetching new values from Remote Config after the user property changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Firebase reload by sending silent FCM message either to devices with specific property value or to all devices. Naturally you need to implement handling for the notification and reload triggering. [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime) page describes the implementation very well.